# overflow-x: visible; doesn't work with overflow-y: auto; any workaround?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

i am trying

```
.item {
   width: 100px;
   overflow-x: visible;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But vertical overflow:auto seems to override horizontal's

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xcUTV/

Is there any workaround for this? even with a bit of javascript

Comment: **Better demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xcUTV/1/

Comment: Btw, you don't have to explicitly set `overflow-x: visible` - that's the default presentation.

Comment: `overflow-y: auto;` means that the vertical scroll-bar may or may not be present. I guess, a vertical scroll-bar represents a horizontal boundary, so the browsers do not allow text to overflow horizontally if a vertical scroll-bar may appear. So, if `overflow-y: auto;` is set, `overflow-x: visible;` does not apply. But that's just my guess.

Comment: Good question. Definitely not the expected behavior. Notice though if you take the wrap out, the issue is gone (when leaving the overflows as described)..

Comment: According to the spec, if one is set to `visible`, and the other to `auto` or `scroll`, then the `visible` is changed to `auto`. If you're happy with a javascript solution, then set both to `hidden` and use one of the javascript scrollers. But I think you should probably revisit what effect you're trying to achieve, because the content would need to get clipped eventually anyway - even if at the window level.

Comment: hey just found your question, maybe ``position: relative`` will do the trick ;) updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dca866zx/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot, that is written in the spec.

Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/1343096

Since it is written in the spec, I am 99% sure that it is impossible to do.

Comment: what about a javascript workaround?

Comment: javascript is not magic! This kind of thing are implemented at a low level by the browser itself, no matter if the instructions comes from css or javascript. I don't say it's not possible, I just say that it would surprised it is, and it would be against the specification.

Comment: it is written specs ?? what does this mean......
are you saying that this is not bug and venders does this intense fully

Comment: @RavinderPayal Yes, that is exactly what that means. Browsers are meant to hide the overflow if there is a scrollbar present, because there should not be a scrollbar halfway down your content.

Comment: There's actually a lot of ways to accomplish this with javascript. One way is to position the element at root (direct child of body) and then use javascript to position the element.

Comment: @PietroCoelho Provide an example then, please, for the sake of the community.