# make the content visible in overflow-y:auto layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

[The code of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jplyue/7esfpste/4/)

```
<article id="mod_2" class="module">
    <header>
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo non, dolorem officiis molestias neque nemo aliquam inventore nostrum beatae voluptatem aspernatur, architecto qui, nihil delectus excepturi libero ipsum error. Sint.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo non, dolorem officiis molestias neque nemo aliquam inventore nostrum beatae voluptatem aspernatur, architecto qui, nihil delectus excepturi libero ipsum error. Sint.</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo non, dolorem officiis molestias neque nemo aliquam inventore nostrum beatae voluptatem aspernatur, architecto qui, nihil delectus excepturi libero ipsum error. Sint.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo non, dolorem officiis molestias neque nemo aliquam inventore nostrum beatae voluptatem aspernatur, architecto qui, nihil delectus excepturi libero ipsum error. Sint.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo non, dolorem officiis molestias neque nemo aliquam inventore nostrum beatae voluptatem aspernatur, architecto qui, nihil delectus excepturi libero ipsum error. Sint.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo non, dolorem officiis molestias neque nemo aliquam inventore nostrum beatae voluptatem aspernatur, architecto qui, nihil delectus excepturi libero ipsum error. Sint.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo non, dolorem officiis molestias neque nemo aliquam inventore nostrum beatae voluptatem aspernatur, architecto qui, nihil delectus excepturi libero ipsum error. Sint.</p>
      <div class="mod_menu">
          <a href=""></a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </article>
```

When you hover the `#innerHtml`, there is a menu `.mod_menu` appearing on the right, which uses absolute position. But the mod_menu is invisible. How to make it visible?

I have searched questions relating to overflow-y auto & overflow-x visible but they didn't work out. Please help me~

Comment: I was going to link to this one as the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903084/overflow-x-visible-doesnt-work-with-overflow-y-auto-any-workaround but that in turn linked to the one I have marked

Comment: @Pete as long as you don't close in a circular manner.

Answer (score 1):

Change `right` to `0px;` in the CSS rule for `.module .mod_menu {...}`

http://jsfiddle.net/5La1qc1s/