# Overflow-y: scroll; on side navigation prevents tooltip functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, overflow

I have a side navigation with the following styles

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 78px;
background: #11101D;
padding: 6px 14px;
z-index: 99;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Which allows the user to scroll vertically on the side navigation.

When a user hovers on a navigation item, a tooltip appears to the right.

```
position: absolute;
top: -20px;
left: calc(100% + 15px);
z-index: 3;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
padding: 6px 12px;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
opacity: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
pointer-events: none;
transition: 0s;
```

However, because of the `overflow-y: scroll;` on the parent, it doesn't overlap the sidebar, instead you scroll horizontally to see it, which isn't desired.

#### Current Tooltip

[image: on hover]
[image: on hover and vertical scroll]

### Desired Tooltip (with side nav scroll functionality)

[image: tooltip visible with scroll]

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/547cqao8/) with all the markup and styles.

I want the the side nav to be vertically scrollable while still having the functionality to view the tooltip.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is based on a React Application, so would prefer non JQuery solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can't, it's "written in the specs"

Source: [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue/6433475#6433475)

Source of the source: [overflow-x: visible; doesn't work with overflow-y: auto; any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903084/overflow-x-visible-doesnt-work-with-overflow-y-auto-any-workaround)

<s>But you can wrap the menu in a container to split the overflows, the parent with `overflow-x: auto` and the child with `overflow-y: scroll`</s>

Comment: I've tried to this but I still face the same issue that the tooltip doesn't appear as expected, perhaps I am going about this in the wrong way? Can you fork my JSFiddle with your solution?

Comment: @mcclosa looks like you are right, my bad. After trying multiple ways it seems that these two can't be combined, I'd suggest a JS lib like tippyJS -> example here: https://embed.plnkr.co/QYgxbD/

Comment: I'll try out tippyJS I was actually in the middle of building a bespoke version of what tippyJS seems to do